# Wordpress, How to filter by taxonomy from custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I created Custom post type named "Syllabi Archive" and added custom taxonomy Named " Program, Academic Year and Semester " and now I want filter post by Taxonomy, Like shown in the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv531.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
 query_posts( array(  
        'post_type' => 'Syllabi Archive', // name without spaces
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // show to all posts
        'tax_query' => array( 
            array( 
                'taxonomy' => 'Program, Academic Year and Semester', //or tag or custom taxonomy without spaces
                'field' => 'id', 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) );
```